# Saving PDF from passport using fs corrupts it

Tags: node.js, pdf, encoding, fs

I'm trying to save a PDF file received via passport into a folder using fs, but for some reason, whenever the file is saved, it is corrupted and can't be read. I've tried with UTF-8, binary and null encoding, but nothing seemed to work. Here's the important part of my code:

```
fs.writeFile("../login/src/public/pdfs/" + email + ".pdf", req.body.expediente, {encoding: null}, function(error2) {
                    if(error2) {return done(error2);}
                });
```

Expediente is the name of the PDF file and email is another parameter passed through passport, so... Not sure what is wrong here. Anyone can give me a hand?

Comment: Are you trying to write a filename as a file content to the file "email + `.pdf`"?

Comment: No, what I'm trying to write is the content of the file that filename refers to

Comment: "Expediente is the name of the PDF file" and `req.body.expediente` is a second argument of `writeFile` call. The second argument is data that should be stored to a file which filename is given as the first argument.

Comment: I explained myself wrong then. The name of the file I'm saving is the first argument (I know that), and the file I wanna save with that name is req.body.expediente (received via passport after checking some other stuff)

Comment: Are you sure you get a Buffer with correct data and length in `req.body.expediente`? Did you use `multer`?